# Submit Form OnChange Text Field Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, textbox

On rails 4.

I am using a text field to display a calendar in which users can select a checkin date. I am trying to figure out how to submit the form onchange, similar to doing so with a select tag.

I tried something like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'from_date_field', params[:from_date_field], 
    class: "input-lg datebox", id: "dpd1", onchange: "this.form.submit();" %>
```

But, since it is a text field, the onchange event does not work. What would be the best way to go about this? Having trouble finding documentation. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `onchange` you can use `onblur`

```
<%= text_field_tag 'from_date_field', params[:from_date_field], class: "input-lg datebox", id: "dpd1", onblur: "this.form.submit();" %>
```

This solution would work when you will take off the focus from the field. But I would suggest you to use an `id` for the form and submit it on `onblur` event.

If you are using `datepicker` to update the date you can use this, you need to define a `onSelect` event while initializing datepicker.

```
$(".date_field").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(date) {
    $("#form").submit();
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this did indeed work. I will accept as soon as I can. Question: How can I delay this function? My calendar isn't able to update because the onblur triggers before the new value is inserted to the text field. @RSB

Comment: How are you inserting the values, are you using `datepicker`?

Comment: So you are using jQuery, I am posting an alternative, you can use `datepicker` `onSelect` event instead.

Comment: To add to the answer. Since this is a text field the onchange function will fire when the element loses focus. As per jQuery docs: For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

@RSB - answer deleted. no use in redundancy.